# Is "Because my feeling into you" the same as "Because I have feelings for you"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, songs

I know song lyrics often contain phrases with words is an order different then usual, or with little sense. I'm not a native English speaker, so I ran into this phrase in a song and had some trouble:

> because my feeling into you

In:

> For the first time I'm in sense of what to do
>   because my feeling into you
>   you know my feeling into you

Can it be rephrased as `because I have feelings for you` or something like that?

Comment: I've found the first line in an internet article: 'For the first time I made sense of I what to do'. This would indicate that the lyrics are not in standard English (or are not reproduced accurately). And song lyrics have been off-topic on ELU because they tend to be far from what many accept as acceptable English.

Comment: All the transcripts of the song seem to have one source. Without auditioning the song I wonder if it is a mistranscription of "I made sense of what I want to do".

Comment: Interested readers can listen to the song ("Barcelona" by Henry Green) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=806rF54zgwc).

Comment: Opinion-based? Really? wtf? I just asked a simple question. Not sure if admins here only read the title or what, but sincerely disappointed with this community. I'm not asking anyone to explain the song to me, I just want to know if one phrase is equal to the other because of it's phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having listened to the excerpt of that song, it does seem those lyrics are correct, which leads me to the conclusion that "my feeling into you" is being used as a noun that refers to the act of the speaker feeling interest in the person listening.

Putting it into the context of the whole phrase, I would interpret it as:

"For the first time, I have an idea of what to do, because I feel interested in you"

This is similar to how someone might say "my running for office changed my perspective on the whole political process."

Comment: Thanks. I have to translate it and was afraid to get it wrong.